# Making a Market Research Tabulation Report in Excel

Tags: excel

I've got a data table that I'm trying to create a tabulation report. Basically, I've got a section with 870 columns that each 7 cuts to be projected into the tabs.

I'd like to create a formula that I can either drag to autofill or have an array that picks out the relative columns and conditions (e.g., men, women, suburban, urban, rural).

Using OFFSET in COUNTIFS doesn't work as it creates volatile function that Excel doesn't like.

SUMIFS doesn't work as I need my criteria to be the same area as my sum range.

I can't make a pivot table create separate lines per response...

Suggestions?

Comment: Almost anything you can do with the volatile OFFSET, you can do with the non-volatile INDEX. Your judgment of SUMIF/SUMIFS is completely wrong.

Comment: Posting screenshots of your excel data would help us helping you